# Activity lifecycle issue

Tags: android

After executing the following code when I kill the application, both the toasts appear on the screen.Now the problem I am facing is that when I comment out the toast in the `onstop` method, the toast in `ondestroy` method doesn't show up. What could be the reason for this?

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onstop",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ondestroy",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Kindly refer this link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: well ill ask again,,i have read about the lifecycle ..when i run this code both toasts appear onstop followed by ondestroy,,but when i commented out toast in onstop method..toast in ondestroy didnt show up..thats the question

Answer (score 0):

You can check your Logcat for the error. Run your app and watch closing the responses on the Logcat.